# SQL group rows by student_id on unique marks for any course

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a SQL table like this:

```
Student_id     mark         course
----------     --------     ---------
1              15           math
1              15           physics
2              15           math
2              16           physics
```

and want to produce this output:

```
Student_id     mark         count
----------     --------     ---------
1              15           2
2              15           1
2              16           1
```

count is **number of single unique mark for each student (on any number of courses)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `student_id`, `mark`, count(1) AS `count`
FROM `the_table`
GROUP BY `student_id`, `mark`
;
```

If you want the results in a certain order, for now "GROUP BY" in MySql does it, but I've recently heard it's been deprecated in the latest versions so you might want to add an ORDER BY after the GROUP BY to future-proof a little.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I will accept it ASAP regarding Stack rules.